# Phonegap 3.0.0 Calendar Plugin

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am looking for a calendar plugin that works with specifically with iOS, though I'd also be interested in an Android plugin too, that is compatible with Phonegap 3.0.0. I have seen the old one, but from what I've seen it does not work with the newest version of Phonegap. Does anyone know of where I can get a plugin that works with Phonegap 3.0.0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If anyone is still looking for a cross-platofrm (iOS and Android) Calendar for PhoneGap 3.0 (also for PhoneGap Build), take a look here: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Calendar-PhoneGap-Plugin

Comment: HI Eddy, calender plugin works on android and IOS. but not working on blackberry.

Comment: Correct, it's iOS and Android only

Comment: Thanks eddy, Any other idea for blackberry.

Comment: Is it compatible with Apache Cordova?

Comment: Yes, it's a Cordova plugin really.

Comment: Good plugin but I just wish when someone creates a plugin, they write the documentation for others and not just for themselves. just saying.

Comment: I actually wrote the plugin and doc for you because I've never used it in one of my own apps. Just saying.

Answer (score 2):

There is an "official" 3rd party Calendar plugin available in the PhoneGap plugin section:

https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/168

Plugin ID
nl.x-services.plugins.calendar

Version
3.2

Platform(s)
Android, iOS

PhoneGap Version(s)
3.0.0, 3.1.0

License
MIT

Answer (score 1):

hi i just build a plugin for android and ios respectively i changed the plugin from Felix Montanez so that it is working with phonegap 3.0.0 for android i used the plugin from devgirl i just changed the javascript that it is working with both platforms:

calendar.js:

```
function CalendarPlugin() {}

CalendarPlugin.prototype.createEvent = function(title, location, notes, startDate, endDate, successCallback, errorCallback) {
    if (typeof errorCallback != "function") {
        console.log("CalendarPlugin.createEvent failure: errorCallback parameter must be a function");
        return;
    }

    if (typeof successCallback != "function") {
        console.log("CalendarPlugin.createEvent failure: successCallback parameter must be a function");
        return;
    }
    cordova.exec(successCallback, errorCallback, "CalendarPlugin", "createEvent", [title, location, notes, startDate, endDate, {
        "title": title,
        "description": notes,
        "eventLocation": location,
        "startTimeMillis": startDate.getTime(),
        "endTimeMillis": endDate.getTime()
    }]);
};

CalendarPlugin.install = function() {
    if (!window.plugins) {
        window.plugins = {};
    }

    window.plugins.CalendarPlugin = new CalendarPlugin();
    return window.plugins.CalendarPlugin;
};

cordova.addConstructor(CalendarPlugin.install);
```

CalendarPlugin.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Cordova/CDVPlugin.h>
#import <Cordova/CDV.h>
#import <EventKitUI/EventKitUI.h>
#import <EventKit/EventKit.h>


@interface CalendarPlugin : CDVPlugin

@property (nonatomic, retain) EKEventStore* eventStore;

- (void)initEventStoreWithCalendarCapabilities;

-(NSArray*)findEKEventsWithTitle: (NSString *)title
                        location: (NSString *)location
                         message: (NSString *)message
                       startDate: (NSDate *)startDate
                         endDate: (NSDate *)endDate;

// Calendar Instance methods

- (void)createEvent:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command;
- (void)modifyEvent:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command;
- (void)findEvent:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command;
- (void)deleteEvent:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command;

@end
```

CalendarPlugin.m

```
#import "CalendarPlugin.h"
#import <EventKitUI/EventKitUI.h>
#import <EventKit/EventKit.h>

#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)

@implementation CalendarPlugin
@synthesize eventStore;

#pragma mark Initialisation functions

- (CDVPlugin*) initWithWebView:(UIWebView*)theWebView
{
    self = (CalendarPlugin*)[super initWithWebView:theWebView];
    if (self) {
        //[self setup];
        [self initEventStoreWithCalendarCapabilities];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)initEventStoreWithCalendarCapabilities {
    __block BOOL accessGranted = NO;
    eventStore= [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
    if([eventStore respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAccessToEntityType:completion:)]) {
        dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
        [eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
            accessGranted = granted;
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
        }];
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    } else { // we're on iOS 5 or older
        accessGranted = YES;
    }

    if (accessGranted) {
        self.eventStore = eventStore;
    }
}

#pragma mark Helper Functions

-(NSArray*)findEKEventsWithTitle: (NSString *)title
                        location: (NSString *)location
                         message: (NSString *)message
                       startDate: (NSDate *)startDate
                         endDate: (NSDate *)endDate {

    // Build up a predicateString - this means we only query a parameter if we actually had a value in it
    NSMutableString *predicateString= [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@""];
    if (title.length > 0) {
        [predicateString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"title == '%@'" , title]];
    }
    if (location.length > 0) {
        [predicateString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" AND location == '%@'" , location]];
    }
    if (message.length > 0) {
        [predicateString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" AND notes == '%@'" , message]];
    }

    NSPredicate *matches = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateString];

    NSArray *datedEvents = [self.eventStore eventsMatchingPredicate:[eventStore predicateForEventsWithStartDate:startDate endDate:endDate calendars:nil]];


    NSArray *matchingEvents = [datedEvents filteredArrayUsingPredicate:matches];


    return matchingEvents;
}

#pragma mark Cordova functions

- (void)createEvent:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command {
    // Import arguments

    NSArray *arguments = command.arguments;

    NSString* title      = [arguments objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* location   = [arguments objectAtIndex:1];
    NSString* message    = [arguments objectAtIndex:2];
    NSString *startDate  = [arguments objectAtIndex:3];
    NSString *endDate    = [arguments objectAtIndex:4];

    //creating the dateformatter object
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    NSDate *myStartDate = [df dateFromString:startDate];
    NSDate *myEndDate = [df dateFromString:endDate];


    EKEvent *myEvent = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore: self.eventStore];
    myEvent.title = title;
    myEvent.location = location;
    myEvent.notes = message;
    myEvent.startDate = myStartDate;
    myEvent.endDate = myEndDate;
    myEvent.calendar = self.eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents;


    EKAlarm *reminder = [EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:-2*60*60];

    [myEvent addAlarm:reminder];

    NSError *error = nil;
    [self.eventStore saveEvent:myEvent span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&error];

    // Check error code + return result
    CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = nil;

    if (!error) {
        pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK];
    } else {
        pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_ERROR];
    }

    [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];

}
-(void)deleteEvent:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command {
    // Import arguments

    NSArray *arguments = command.arguments;

    NSString* title      = [arguments objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* location   = [arguments objectAtIndex:1];
    NSString* message    = [arguments objectAtIndex:2];
    NSString *startDate  = [arguments objectAtIndex:3];
    NSString *endDate    = [arguments objectAtIndex:4];
    bool delAll = [arguments objectAtIndex:5];

    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    NSDate *myStartDate = [df dateFromString:startDate];
    NSDate *myEndDate = [df dateFromString:endDate];

    NSArray *matchingEvents = [self findEKEventsWithTitle:title location:location message:message startDate:myStartDate endDate:myEndDate];


    if (delAll || matchingEvents.count == 1) {
        // Definitive single match - delete it!
        NSError *error = NULL;
        bool hadErrors = false;
        if (delAll) {
            for (EKEvent * event in matchingEvents) {
                [self.eventStore removeEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&error];
                // Check for error codes and return result
                if (error) {
                    hadErrors = true;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            [self.eventStore removeEvent:[matchingEvents lastObject] span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&error];
        }
        // Check for error codes and return result
        CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = nil;
        if (error || hadErrors) {
            NSString *messageString;
            if (hadErrors) {
                messageString = @"Error deleting events";
            }
            else {
                messageString = error.userInfo.description;
            }
                pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_ERROR
                                                              messageAsString:messageString];

        }
        else {
                pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK];
        }
        [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
    }

}

-(void)findEvent:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command {
    // Import arguments

    NSArray *arguments = command.arguments;

    NSString* title      = [arguments objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* location   = [arguments objectAtIndex:1];
    NSString* message    = [arguments objectAtIndex:2];
    NSString *startDate  = [arguments objectAtIndex:3];
    NSString *endDate    = [arguments objectAtIndex:4];

    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    NSDate *myStartDate = [df dateFromString:startDate];
    NSDate *myEndDate = [df dateFromString:endDate];

    NSArray *matchingEvents = [self findEKEventsWithTitle:title location:location message:message startDate:myStartDate endDate:myEndDate];

    NSMutableArray *finalResults = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:matchingEvents.count];


    // Stringify the results - Cordova can't deal with Obj-C objects
    for (EKEvent * event in matchingEvents) {
        NSMutableDictionary *entry = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                      event.title, @"title",
                                      event.location, @"location",
                                      event.notes, @"message",
                                      [df stringFromDate:event.startDate], @"startDate",
                                      [df stringFromDate:event.endDate], @"endDate", nil];
        [finalResults addObject:entry];
    }
    CDVPluginResult *pluginResult = nil;
    if (finalResults.count > 0) {
        // Return the results we got
        pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult
                                   resultWithStatus: CDVCommandStatus_OK
                                   messageAsArray:finalResults
                                   ];
        [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
    }
    else {
        pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_NO_RESULT];
    }
    [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];

}


-(void)modifyEvent:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command {
    // Import arguments

    NSArray *arguments = command.arguments;

    NSString* title      = [arguments objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* location   = [arguments objectAtIndex:1];
    NSString* message    = [arguments objectAtIndex:2];
    NSString *startDate  = [arguments objectAtIndex:3];
    NSString *endDate    = [arguments objectAtIndex:4];

    NSString* ntitle      = [arguments objectAtIndex:5];
    NSString* nlocation   = [arguments objectAtIndex:6];
    NSString* nmessage    = [arguments objectAtIndex:7];
    NSString *nstartDate  = [arguments objectAtIndex:8];
    NSString *nendDate    = [arguments objectAtIndex:9];

    // Make NSDates from our strings
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    NSDate *myStartDate = [df dateFromString:startDate];
    NSDate *myEndDate = [df dateFromString:endDate];

    // Find matches
    NSArray *matchingEvents = [self findEKEventsWithTitle:title location:location message:message startDate:myStartDate endDate:myEndDate];

    CDVPluginResult *pluginResult = nil;

    if (matchingEvents.count == 1) {
        // Presume we have to have an exact match to modify it!
        // Need to load this event from an EKEventStore so we can edit it
        EKEvent *theEvent = [self.eventStore eventWithIdentifier:((EKEvent*)[matchingEvents lastObject]).eventIdentifier];
        if (ntitle) {
            theEvent.title = ntitle;
        }
        if (nlocation) {
            theEvent.location = nlocation;
        }
        if (nmessage) {
            theEvent.notes = nmessage;
        }
        if (nstartDate) {
            NSDate *newMyStartDate = [df dateFromString:nstartDate];
            theEvent.startDate = newMyStartDate;
        }
        if (nendDate) {
            NSDate *newMyEndDate = [df dateFromString:nendDate];
            theEvent.endDate = newMyEndDate;
        }

        // Now save the new details back to the store
        NSError *error = nil;
        [self.eventStore saveEvent:theEvent span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&error];

        // Check error code + return result
        if (error) {
            pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_ERROR
                                                               messageAsString:error.userInfo.description];

        }
        else {
            pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK];
        }
    }
    else {
        // Otherwise return a no result error
        pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_NO_RESULT];
    }
    [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
}
@end
```

CalendarPlugin.java

```
package de.drid.calendarPlugin;

import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import android.content.Intent;

public class CalendarPlugin extends CordovaPlugin {
    public static final String ACTION_ADD_CALENDAR_ENTRY = "createEvent";

    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
        try {
            if (ACTION_ADD_CALENDAR_ENTRY.equals(action)) { 
                JSONObject arg_object = args.getJSONObject(5);
                Intent calIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT)
                    .setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event")
                    .putExtra("beginTime", arg_object.getLong("startTimeMillis"))
                    .putExtra("endTime", arg_object.getLong("endTimeMillis"))
                    .putExtra("title", arg_object.getString("title"))
                    .putExtra("description", arg_object.getString("description"))
                    .putExtra("eventLocation", arg_object.getString("eventLocation"));

                   this.cordova.getActivity().startActivity(calIntent);
                   callbackContext.success();
                   return true;
            }
            callbackContext.error("Invalid action");
            return false;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            callbackContext.error(e.getMessage());
            return false;
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a PhoneGap Calendar Plugin for Android](http://devgirl.org/2013/07/17/tutorial-how-to-write-a-phonegap-plugin-for-android/) that will work with 3.0

For PG 3.0 you’ll need to modify the import statements in the .java class as it changed from 2.9:

From this…

```
import org.apache.cordova.api.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.api.CordovaPlugin;
```

to this…

```
import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
```

Comment: Is there anything out there that works cross platform? I need it to support iOS too.

Comment: @NathanStanfordII I didn't have any luck finding a plugin that supports both platforms and has the same JavaScript API that interfaces with the native environment (Java/Objective-C).