# Phonegap 3 Calendar plugin for IOS Error on createNewEvent

Tags: ios, calendar, phonegap-plugins

I am trying to get the calendar plugin to work with ios and Phonegap 3: 
DrDawnamight made it Phonegap 3 compatible here: [Phonegap 3.0.0 Calendar Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18622090/phonegap-3-0-0-calendar-plugin/19413891#19413891)

Everything compiles in xCode 5 without issue but I am having a problem creating a calendar event... I used all the code that DrDawnamight posted but I get this in the console:

```
2013-10-16 15:59:08.675 Talon[589:60b] *** Assertion failure in -[UIApplication runModal:](), /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2903.2/UIApplication.m:9467
2013-10-16 15:59:08.676 Talon[589:60b] *** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage:initiatedByFrame: delegate: <NSInternalInconsistencyException> The view passed in does not have a window.
```

and I get this in an alert:

```
Index.html
createCalEvent: TypeError: 'undefined' is not an onject (evaluating 'window.plugins.calendarPlugin.createEvent')
```

any idea what I may have screwed up?

Answer (score 0):

you could try this one for PhoneGap 3.x (also for PhoneGap Build): https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Calendar-PhoneGap-Plugin

Answer (score 0):

You could try [this](https://github.com/hazemhagrass/phonegap-calendar-plugin) one for both Android and iOS