# how to integrate google calendar on phonegap application

Tags: cordova, google-calendar-api

Is possible to put google calendar on a phonegap application?

I'm trying to make a website with a google calendar and a mobile application who can acces already to this calendar.

It is for use in an iOS Application.

Comment: hope this [plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Calendar-PhoneGap-Plugin) help

Comment: Question is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18622090/phonegap-3-0-0-calendar-plugin